# Restrict the dragging/movement of smart lines in fusioncharts to avoid weird shapes

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm creating doughnut chart with smart lines and labels. When there is only one item in the chart, I'm facing an issue. If you drag the smart label or line around, the chart changes its shape in some angles. When the doughnut chart has 3-4 items this doesn't occur. I have attached screenshots. Is there any way to fix this or disable the rotation of chart when lines/labels are dragged?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a Bug. Can you tell me which version you are using and whether you see this problem on all browsers? Please create a fiddle or give us the data; at least the chart level attributes.

Comment: I'm using version 3.9.0. This occurs in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/g1254w67/ 
Drag one of the labels around and you can see the wonky chart.

Comment: It is indeed a bug and seems, is related to the pies with zero value. I could not replicate this when the value is 2. Reported as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the dragging of `smartlines`, add `"enableRotation": "0"` to the chart object. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g1254w67/19/